# Nuget Package: Use Different MVC Version When Available

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget, nuget-package

I've got an open source nuget package [AttributeRouting](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting). Currently the packaged assemblies reference System.Web.Mvc version 2. I'd like to reference MVC 3/4 in MVC 3/4 projects, so that users of Windows 8/VS 2011 don't have to install MVC 2 to use the package. Anyone know of a way to do this? Google has not been my friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current, Nuget can't do this.  This is why there are separate MVC2 and MVC3 packages of libraries in the Nuget gallery.

So you have to create a separate Nuget package for MVC3 and MVC4 (if necessary)

Comment: Not only that but there are breaking changes in MVC2, MVC3 and MVC4. How would you possibly create a package that can be compatiable with all three or even future compatiable with MVC5?

Comment: @NickBork - the same way you can currently create a package that targets various .NET versions.  NuGet could support multiple MVC versions, but right now, it doesn't.  I suppose you could write a powershell script to execute and figure out which version somehow.. but that would be a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

You can add into your Nuget package the assemblies for all supported versions of MVC and then use install.ps1 script to remove unnecessary ones and leave only the assembly which is compatible with MVC version used in the target project.

You will find more detailed instructions and an example of install.ps1 script here:
http://blogs.korzh.com/2013/12/nuget-package-different-mvc-versions.html