# Nuget package the depends on 1 of N Nuget packages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget, nuget-package

I am working on an open source project [MvcSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider) getting it ready for deployment. It is a library package that supports MVC2, MVC3, and MVC4 as well as .NET 3.5, .NET 4.0, and .NET 4.5.

Based on [Nuget Package: Use Different MVC Version When Available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845413/nuget-package-use-different-mvc-version-when-available), I have come to the conclusion that I need to make a Nuget package for each version of MVC and let Nuget's internal version detection take care of the different .NET versions, like this:

- MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC2
- MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC3
- MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4

However, in addition to a library DLL, I have different files (Dependency Injection configuation, MVC DisplayTemplates, etc.) that need to be deployed to the target project. These files **MUST NOT** be updated when the new version of the main project is updated because they will likely contain end-developer edits that I don't want to overwrite.

So, it is clear that these need to be in their own Nuget packages for this and other reasons. However, these other packages need to depend on the main MvcSiteMapProvider.MVCx projects, just to ensure one of them has been installed.

It doesn't make sense to make a separate Nuget package for each version of MVC for each of these other packages - they are all exactly the same except for this one dependency. Ideally what I would like to do is make a single Nuget package that depends on either MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC2, MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC3, or MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4 and if none of them are available, install the one that matches the MVC version of the target project, but how would I accomplish this? If that is not possible, what other options do I have than creating large number of Nuget packages (one for each MVC version dependency) that grows exponentially with each new MVC release?

To clarify, I have other Nuget packages like this:

- MvcSiteMapProvider.Web
- MvcSiteMapProvider.Configuration.Autofac
- MvcSiteMapProvider.Configuration.Ninject
- MvcSiteMapProvider.Configuration.StructureMap
- MvcSiteMapProvider.Configuration.Unity
- MvcSiteMapProvider.Configuration.Windsor

I am trying to avoid having to change that to:

- MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC2.Web
- MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC2.Configuration.Autofac
- MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC2.Configuration.Ninject
- MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC2.Configuration.StructureMap
- MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC2.Configuration.Unity
- MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC2.Configuration.Windsor
- MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC3.Web
- MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC3.Configuration.Autofac
- MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC3.Configuration.Ninject
- MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC3.Configuration.StructureMap
- MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC3.Configuration.Unity
- MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC3.Configuration.Windsor
- MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4.Web
- MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4.Configuration.Autofac
- MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4.Configuration.Ninject
- MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4.Configuration.StructureMap
- MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4.Configuration.Unity
- MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4.Configuration.Windsor

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your source code, it seems like you are [referencing multiple versions](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/packages.config) of the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc package in MvcSiteMapProvider project. I am not sure this is working as you expect it to since there can be only one version of System.Web.Mvc that can be put in the bin folder during the compilation process (the latest version 5.0.0 will be used).

So any code in your package that depends on Mvc V3 or V4 is not really getting the dll it expects.

Since most of the packages you referenced above like Autofac also have integration package that target specific MVC versions,you may not have an option but to split your package into smaller packages like you mentioned in your post.

A better approach to this problem would be to separate the Core functionality provided by your package which does not have dependency on any version of MVC. You can then create different wrapper packages that depend on your core package and also on a specific version of Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc. And create similar packages for each different Configuration has a nuget dependency on third party packages like Autofac (eg [Autofac.Mvc5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Mvc5/)) and its corresponding version of your MvcSiteMapProvider.MvcX package

Comment: Thanks. I am relying on the conditional behavior of MSBuild to [select the appropriate dependencies](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider.csproj#L48) depending on which version of MVC to build for. That part is working fine. My issue is with the fact that there is no way to specify package X or Y or Z as required, and install package Z if none of them are installed. Anyway, this issue is moot since I have learned that this is a [conforming container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/conforming-container/).